# Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain - profile file cannot be null

Tags: spring, spring-boot, amazon-sns

I'm trying to use AmazonSNS in my Spring Boot application and I'm able to use it locally, but as soon as I'm deploying it on my development server, I'm getting this error:

```
Caused by: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain: [com.amazonaws.auth.EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper@46a123e4: The requested metadata is not found at http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/ , com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider@44bc2449: profile file cannot be null]
```

If I don't get it wrong, my server is not able to get any AWS credentials. I don't understand why, because AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY are set as environment variables. My code looks like that:

```
private AmazonSNS amazonSNS;

@Autowired
public AmazonSNSPublisherService() {
    this.amazonSNS = AmazonSNSClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.getInstance()).withRegion("eu-west-1").build();
}
```

I tried this:

```
this.amazonSNS = AmazonSNSClientBuilder.standard().withRegion("eu-west-1").build();
```

And this:

```
this.amazonSNS = AmazonSNSClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(new EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider()).withRegion("eu-west-1").build();
```

But I'm always getting the same error.

Comment: can you confirm AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY exists in your env?

Comment: @slimane When I look the "environment" tab in my pod (in the OpenShift web console), both variables are present.

Comment: I had a look at docs, I thing DEBUG will show more informations about the error, can you enable it and post the logs?

Comment: Thanks @slimane, you put me on the right track to find the solution (see above).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 years too late - but I think I figured it out.

As @vincentS pointed out - it has to do with that dependency. But you not need remove it.

Set the property

`cloud.aws.credentials.useDefaultAwsCredentialsChain = true`

in your application (Yaml or properties) and you are good to go. (This works for me).

Source: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/reference/html/

Comment: Thanks!! More than 2 hours trying to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot explain why, but my problem was this dependency in my pom file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

As soon as I removed it, the DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to diagnose your specific problem, but I had the same issue, also in a Spring Boot application.  The reason was because Spring Boot (potentially the spring-cloud-starter-aws package) creates its own Credentials Provider Chain and where I had placed

```
@Autowired
private AmazonS3 s3Client;
```

Was injected into the Spring bean container BEFORE my @Bean method was executed:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public AWSCredentialsProvider buildDefaultAWSCredentialsProvider() {
    return new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain();
}
```

In fact, I put both snippets in the same @Configuration class and I didn't realize the @Autowired bean was injected from the Spring container (which starts out with AmazonS3 client and DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain credential created by Spring Boot) before my @Bean was instantiated and inserted into the Spring container.

Anyways, try looking to see if you're @Autowired injecting the credentials OR a client that uses it in a place that gets executed before YOUR credentials and YOUR SNS client.